# Animation starts moving out of position after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a sort of slideshow animation. I have the codes here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nRHag/).

These tablets would rotate around.

The problem is that, at random times, the animation will move out of line. The wrong tablets undergo wrong animations. Here are the screenshots:

[image: When everything is fine]

And this is how it looks like when the animations goes wrong

[image: when the animation goes wrong]

The main problem is I don't understand why the animation would go wrong random times. In my computer it will run properly for hours, but in other cases (especially on Safari).

Comment: Your JSFiddle has errors that stop it from running at all. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'position' of null`. `Uncaught ReferenceError: doit is not defined`

Comment: I am not too familiar with jsFiddle. Please see www.nxgenlabs.co.uk for the live sample.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `In my computer it will run properly for hours, but in other cases`... What other cases? What browser(s) behave improperly?

Comment: I mean when the site is opened using another computer, mostly a slower one, there is a higher chance of seeing the animation going wrong. And using safari (in my computer or any other) the animation goes wrong straight away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the expected final css values for each animated el and then in the animate callback set these values, so for each animated el something like

```
var el = $(selector);

el.data("finalCSS", { your expected final CSS values })

$("selector").animate({animation properties}, function() {
     el.css(el.data("finalCSS")).data("finalCSS", undefined);
})
```

This doesn't help with figuring out why it's happening (but I can't recreate the issue myself), but provides a failsafe to make sure the layout doesn't break;

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens when you try to animate before the previous animation has ended. Use **[jQuery stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** just before you animate. For example:

```
$('#animatingDiv').stop(false, true).animate({height:300}, 200, callback);
```

The first param(false) will empty the animation queue on that element and the second param(true) will jumps to the end of current animation before starting a new animation.

Comment: I gave it a try, but after leaving the animation overnight, the animation still went wrong. But stopping the animation before the next one is a good suggestion. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately there's no working example on jsFiddle, but I believe the calculations you are doing for the animation is going wrong by minute value which becomes noticeable as time passes. Or, you're calculating it wrong for one the slides which wrecks the whole. I might be wrong. Can't help much without seeing a working sample.

Comment: To see the animation in action, please visit www.nxgenlabs.co.uk. I have implemented a temporary fix by reloading the divs using ajax. I noticed that there is a higher chance of the animation going wrong when I left the animation running while browsing on other pages or running other application. I think you're right that the animation goes wrong by minute value somewhere as time passes

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with far less code and far fewer headaches.

**1. Store your tablet position attributes in classes**

```
.tablet1{
  height:100px;
  width:140px;
  margin-left:-540px;
  top: 200px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

**2. Use a general function to handle all your transitions.**

JQuery UI will do all the work for you if you use `switchClass`

```
switchTabletsRight = function(){
  var i, next, max = 5;
  for(i = 1; i <= max; i++){
    next = (i < max)? i + 1 : 1;
    $(".tablet" + i).switchClass("tablet" + i, "tablet" + next);
  }
};​
```

Here's the JSfiddle proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/nRHag/4/

Comment: Tested on Firefox, Safari, Chrome and IE8/9.

Answer (score 0):

**You are setting CSS positions to decimal values.**

```
    img_w = $("#tablet"+num+" img").width();
    img_w = img_w *140 / 600;
    img_h = $("#tablet"+num+" img").height();
    img_h = img_h *140 /600;
    ...
    var new_width = $(this).width() * 140 / 600;
    $(this).css('width', new_width);
    var new_height = $(this).height() * 140 / 600;
    $(this).css('height', new_height);
```

Your division could be cause decimal results which have different effects in different browsers. Sub pixel CSS positioning may be creating your unintended errors.

Comment: but this is only for the images. is it possible that this might affect the tablets movement as well?